# Is it possible to remap LMB (shield) to Shift in Dark Souls 2 on PC?

Tags: dark-souls-2, keyboard

I find the game to be completely unplayable with the new keybindings - disappointing does not even begin to cover it (double left click and double right click, **SERIOUSLY**?)

I want the old DS shift to block setup. Frustratingly, in-game options give you a predefined list of absolutely pointless key combos for these things, but not any key you want.

Am I missing something simple here?

Comment: If you can, go and buy a gamepad. DS II will be a much better experience. I bought one just for DS and never regretted it. Keyboard + DS = PAIN!

Comment: Couldn't agree more! I believe the steam version of DS 1 carried a warning about a gamepad being basically nescessary to enjoy the game at all. You will have a miserable time without one, for sure. I don't know the answer to your question, but I suspect it's simply: No, you are not. They keyboard controls really are this awful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, here's how you do it. Go install [AutoHotkey](http://www.autohotkey.com/). After it's installed, it'll create a script in My Documents folder. Edit it, and add the following in there:

```
LButton::h
RButton::g
Shift::u
Xbutton2::y
^!q::ExitApp
```

This corresponds to the Combat settings in-game (which you cannot change to mouse clicks normally). So, in game, H is normal attack, G is strong attack, etc.

The script remaps LButton and RButton to H and G respectively and then shift to U (hold shift now raises the shield). I also set Xbutton2 (which is the browser-back button) to parry (Y in game), but your mileage may vary depending on if you even have that button.

Finally, Ctrl+Alt+Q will quit AutoHotkey.

So what you do is this: Start the game, spawn your character. Tab out of the game, start AutoHotkey, then tab back into the game (keep in mind your clicks are now disabled so you'll have to use Alt+Tab to enter the game)

Ta-da! Old Dark Souls control scheme.

Answer (score 0):

Just add

> Shift::u

Anywhere in the AHK script and reload it, that will make Shift block for you like in DS...

Lots of other useful things you can do like 1 click jump attack and guard break, just add:

> ;Guard Break
>   2::
>   {
>   Send {W down}
>   Sleep 20
>   Send {H down}
>   Sleep 20
>   Send {W up}
>   Send {H up}
>   return
>   }
>
> ;Jump Attack
>   R::
>   {
>   Send {W down}
>   Sleep 20
>   Send {G down}
>   Sleep 20
>   Send {W up}
>   Send {G up}
>   return
>   }